# Login to API Server Failed

Tags: android, http

I have a problem to login to API server with my code,
in API documentation I should login using username,password and key to use the API.

The url login is : `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/Session/login?context=api&skey=2354e5rufygbiuk7bikuyhboulygh&USR=zzzz&PWD=xxx`.

When I execute the url above using httpURLConnection, the server give "OK" response which mean login is succesfull.

But when I try to check that it has login or not using: `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/Session/isLogin?context=api`, the server give "FALSE" response which mean that it hasn't logged in, so I can't use the API.

It just happen when I try to connect using my Android application, but when I try to login via web browser, login is successful and successful when I check it.

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: do you have internet permission in your manifest?

Comment: Yes, i have,,the server is replay also. It say that login is sucessfull,but when i check isLogin or not, it says I'm not loged in. so i can't use the API.

Comment: Think about the session related stuff. Your browser contains a session manager, how about your application? I have no idea about your Application, but you can chek it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the session info from the first request by getHeaderField, and get the session info by regex.

```
    String session_value=getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
```

And use the session info  for the next request.

```
    URL url = new URL(link);
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    //fetch session
    session_value = urlConnection.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
    String[] sessionId = session_value.split(";");
    //set session to do more operation
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", sessionId[0])
```

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think TimonWang has given a good respons that should probably help you.

---

*If you manage the server yourself, I would suggest another solution. In other cases, just ignore this post.*

If I were you I would make the API more RESTful, that means that you will not work with sessions to save your state. The login should in that case return something like an authentication token (which is unique for every login/user) which has to be saved somewhere. When the login is successful the authentication token can be used for later requests. So the authentication token should be saved on the device during the complete session, and should be added to every request you send to the server during that session. The server can see which of the users it is, because of the uniqueness of the authentication token.

So:

```
Login: returns auth_token
Every request: http://example.org/api?key=value&auth_token={auth_token}
```